# Is there a way to handle unexpected int values gracefully when using str.replace?

Tags: python, string, replace, int

I am trying to replace all instances of a substring with a different substring. The string which I am performing this action on can occasionally be a nan `<class 'float'>` instead.

My current code is `x.replace('\n\n', '\n')`. This works fine when the 'x' variable is a string. However, 'x' can also be a nan. When a nan value is used the error `AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'replace'` is returned.

I am looking for something which acts like `x.replace('\n\n', '\n', on_float='ignore')` Such that calling `x.replace('\n\n', '\n')` where x is `<class 'float'>` would return an unchanged variable 'x'.

Comment: Now just add example input and desired output...

Comment: How is an `on_float` parameter of method `replace` supposed to work if that method is not present in the first place?

Comment: Why do you have a variable that can hold both strings and floats? That's a code smell. I would take a step back and change your program so it doesn't happen, rather than try to code around it.

Comment: I am reading an excel file and `pd.read_excel` treats blank cells as nan with class float.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python's exception system is so tempting:

```
try:
    x = x.replace('\n\n', '\n')
except AttributeError:
    pass
```

In this way, not only floats, but also everything that doesn't have a `.replace()` method will be safely ignored, no matter what it is.

Or wrap it up:

```
def universal_replace(x, a, b):
    try:
        return x.replace(a, b)
    except AttributeError:
        return x
```

Then you can safely walk through everything:

```
x = universal_replace(x, '\n\n', '\n')
```

You can also implement your own code in the `except` clause to handle other data types better.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if your element is a string before performing the replace operation!

```
>>> def check_and_replace(x, f, t):
...     if isinstance(x,str):
...             return x.replace('\n\n', '\n')
...     return x
... 
>>> check_and_replace('5', '\n\n', '\n')
'5'
>>> check_and_replace(5, '\n\n', '\n')
5
>>> check_and_replace(type('5'), '\n\n', '\n')
<type 'str'>
```